# Using a complicated function as color function

Tags: plotting, color

I have an ellipsoid with parametric equations

```
lst = {10*Cos[u]*Sin[v], 3*Sin[u]*Sin[v], 2*Cos[v]};
```

I define a function

```
dam = Sqrt[(1296*Cos[u]^4*
       Sin[v]^4)/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 36*Cos[u]^2*Sin[v]^2 + 
        400*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2)^2 + 
         (3600*Cos[u]^2*
       Sin[v]^2*(9*Cos[v]^2 + 4*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2))/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 
        4*(9*Cos[u]^2 + 100*Sin[u]^2)*Sin[v]^2)^2];
```

and a color function as

```
colFun = Function[{u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]];
```

My ultimate goal is coloring the ellipsoid according to the values of

```
Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]
```

So, my question is why there is a big mismatch in the color rendering in the following plots

```
h = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> colFun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 800]; 
g = Plot3D[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}], {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
   Mesh -> False, ColorFunction -> colFun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All]; 
Row[{Show[h], Show[g, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

From `g` we see that the edges of the ellipsoid should be colored with purple color since for the respective angles `{u, v}`, `dam` takes the highest values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following:

```
h = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 800];
g = Plot3D[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}], {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (Function[{u, v, z}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All];
Row[{h, Show[g, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

give what you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {10*Cos[u]*Sin[v], 3*Sin[u]*Sin[v], 2*Cos[v]};
dam = FullSimplify@
   Sqrt[(1296*Cos[u]^4*
        Sin[v]^4)/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 36*Cos[u]^2*Sin[v]^2 + 
         400*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2)^2 + (3600*Cos[u]^2*
        Sin[v]^2*(9*Cos[v]^2 + 4*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2))/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 
         4*(9*Cos[u]^2 + 100*Sin[u]^2)*Sin[v]^2)^2];
```

Add FullSimplify in dam, so now:

```
?dam
```

[image]

```
colFun = Function[{u, v}, Evaluate@Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]];
```

Add Evaluate in colfun, so now:

```
?colfun
```

[image]

```
h = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False,ImageSize -> 300];
```

Change ColorFunction -> colFun to  ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &).Since ColorFunction will receive x,y,z,u,v in ParametricPlot3D, and your colFun just need u,v.

```
g = Plot3D[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}], {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
   Mesh -> False, ColorFunction -> colFun, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All];
Row[{Show[h], Show[g, ImageSize -> 200]}]
```

[image]

For example,ColorFunction will receive x,y,z in Plot3D,so:

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear to me how this answers the question. Please help the OP by explaining how changing `ImageSize` makes a difference. Posting the output graphics might help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies!

Comment: I do know if I should ask a new thread. Why the following (referring to the same situation) does not produce a bar legend?  Legended[g, BarLegend[{colFun, {0, 1}}]]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could also color your ellipsoid f.e. by its mean curvature:

```
 mcur = (a b c (3 (a^2 + b^2) + 2 c^2 + (a^2 + b^2 - 2 c^2) Cos[2 v] + 
     2 (-a^2 + b^2) Cos[2 u] Sin[v]^2))/( 8 (a^2 b^2 Cos[v]^2 + 
      c^2 (b^2 Cos[u]^2 + a^2 Sin[u]^2) Sin[v]^2)^(3/2));
```

Plug in your parameters:

```
dam = mcur /. {a -> 10, b -> 3, c -> 2} // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
 Mesh -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Or use one of the inbuilt color tables:

```
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
 Mesh -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][dam]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]